# How can I configure triggering in IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer?

Tags: ibm-mq

I would like to write a .net Trigger Monitor. But at first I would like just to configure a triggered queue. In accordance with this url http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg13840a.gif when I configure application queue, after putting messages to application queue, messages should appear in initiation queue. But it does not happen and I cannot see any trigger messages in initiation queue. Please, help me to configure a simple example.

Comment: Have you looked at the .NET Monitor? This link gives you more details: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/un10650_.htm. MQ v6 link is this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10660_.htm

Comment: I have looked at it. But I don't want to write a .Net Monitor. As I understand, I can just configure a local queue, set up triggering for it, than configure an initiation queue, than I should write a program that will listen to initiation queue and when I will push a message in application queue, MQ Manager should put a trigger message to the initiation queue. But I do not see any messages in initiation queue, so triggering doesn't work and I am trying to find , what I've set up wrong.

Comment: My problem is very similar to that one: http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=45405&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0 I cannot check whether triggering works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds like you are trying to cause trigger messages to prove that they go to the initiation queue (say by displaying the curdepth) and then next you will attach a trigger monitor program to that queue - once you know that trigger messages are going to the initiation queue.

This will not work I'm afraid. Trigger messages will only be produced on an initiation queue IF a trigger monitor program has the queue open for input. So in order to 'see' the messages go on the initiation queue, you must at minimum have some application with the initiation queue open for input. If you want to be able to display the curdepth and see the messages on the queue, you would need an application that wasn't going to immediately consume them of course!

Answer (score 0):

Here show your an example for tiggering a sender channel whenever there is message arrives transmission queue:
[image]